# How to stop windows from Installing a driver

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, drivers

I have an Ethernet hardware on the mother board ( Boardcon family ethernet ) 
for some reason whenever the windows runs for 30+ mins the internet will disconnect itself. so i thought it was because of the driver and went to get a new lan card and installed, and uninstalled the driver of the old card.

but here is where the issue came up.. windows will always reinstall the driver on restart and then internet will drop due to the driver being there.

can anyway give me a suggestion to stop it from installing at all? and just leave it there as unknown device ?

I tried this but have no results. 
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/stop-windows-7-from-installing-drivers-automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Mother Board has 1 Lan connection line and the onboard one that is broken keeps fighting for that open slot with the PCI Lan.

In BIOS there is a setting to disable onboard hardware and not run them which solved this issue completely after I shutdown the hardware and removed all hidden driver related to it.

Answer (score 1):

In Device Manager uninstall the driver for the device, then disable the device and reboot. The driver should not affect your system henceforth so if your connection still drops intermittently you probably have other problems.

**Edit:** There are two ways to remove the driver manually:

1. Type `pnputil -e` at the command prompt and indentify the .INF file associated with your device. Then type `pnputil -d <INF name>` to get rid of it.
2. Go to Device Manager and view the Properties page for the device. On the *Details* tab, check for the value corresponding to the *Inf name* property. This will give you the .INF name. Now open an elevated (admin) command prompt at `Windows\inf` and delete **Name.inf** and the associated **Name.pnf**.

Comment: I would like to add be sure you select the option to delete the driver when you uninstall the old device.

Comment: i will check this

Comment: What could other problems be in this case?

Comment: Have you tried with a different modem/router?

Comment: the same cable works on another machine when plugged in, so i ruled out that it is the modem / router issue.

Comment: still disconnects, would it be the cheap lan card I brought off (used) that is causing this?... its hard to believe that both card would see this issue. altho the current card it works after disable -> enable

Comment: Your comment [here](http://superuser.com/questions/914864/lan-disconnects-brought-new-lan-card-but-old-one-comes-back#comment1230972_914864) suggests you disabled the network *connection*, but I'm repeatedly telling you to disable the *network adapter device* itself in Device Manager. Have you done that? It's pointless posing the same question repeatedly without getting a proper answer.

Comment: yea i have tried that. the network keep going down in a while.. not sure if its the motherborad or the used pci lan card i replaced with. trying to find a solution to this issue