# LAN disconnects, brought new LAN card but old one comes back

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, drivers, lan

So here is the story, the old LAN port came with the motherboard and after installing windows 8.1 (from windows 7) the LAN would drop in about 30 mins of a restart and never connect again.

I thought it might be a driver issue on the motherboard, so I brought a new LAN and plugged it in on the PCI slot and switched the cable over to that port.

Now the disconnect happens still but happens when the old driver comes back installed (after reboot). when I re-uninstall it and then disable and re-enable the new driver everything seems to work fine...

My question is

1) what seems to be the real cause of this issue?

2) How to Completely remove the old driver and not have windows auto detect and install that driver every-time windows reboots or rescan for hardware changes?

-I have uninstalled from device manager-

Comment: Don't uninstall it, disable it in the profile.

Comment: profile? device manager?

Comment: I too advised you to disable the device in response to your [previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/913615/how-to-stop-windows-from-installing-a-driver), which this one is basically a duplicate of and which you should have edited instead of adding a new one. Did you do it? Are you saying the uninstalled driver gets reinstalled even for a disabled device?

Comment: How do i Combine both? I went to the network connections and there it lists your wifi and lan connections. I first disabled it from that screen then went to configure and then the driver configure and uninstalled.

Comment: "profile? device manager?" It's the option you passed by in order to get to Uninstall